# NullPointerException when loading keystore

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, pfx, pkcs#12

I'm trying to load a keystore from a pfx file, but when i try to upload a pfx file and load the keystore with the code below, it gave me a NullPointerException. The password and the my baos (ByteArrayOutputStream) are not null. Any idea what might be happening?

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
String passw = passwordField.getValue();
ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), passw.toCharArray());
```

This code works with a lot of certificates, but in a specific pfx file this is gaving me this problem:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:491)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.loadSafeContents(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2286)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2025)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably [this line](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/pkcs12/PKCS12KeyStore.java#L2248). The `keyId` is `null` for some reason.

Comment: This looks like a very specific problem, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem few days ago.
In my case the problem was the pfx file that was exported without/wrongly the certificate itself and the private key. It just contained the public key chain of trust.

The solution was to export again the pfx file.

Check your pfx file with this program in Windows (from Kent Chen article):
https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-check-a-pfx-certifications-expiry-date-on-windows

Or in linux use:

> openssl pkcs12 -info -in *certificate_name*.p12

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow !! please add relevant tags.

Comment: Thanks! That was it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide the path for key store file.

```
KeyStore  keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
File f = new File(KEY_STORE_FILE);
if (!f.exists())
{   
   throw new Exception("File Not Found");
 }
 InputStream input = new FileInputStream(KEY_STORE_FILE);
 keyStore.load(input, KEY_STORE_PASS);
 input.close();
 return keyStore;
```

here all the constants are being loaded from config file.

Comment: Can you please get the exception here ? At what line you are getting null pointer exception because this is piece of code is working for me.

Comment: Also, what is extension of the file, .p12 or .pfx ? If it is pfx, and if posssible can you try with p12 extension.

Comment: I'am getting a null pointer exception at this line:ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), passw.toCharArray());

Comment: File extension is .pfx.

Comment: Sorry, i can only use pfx extension

Comment: I think this is a really specific case, any ideas of what it might be ?

Comment: How did you created you pfx file ? The problem should be with the creation of pfx file.